# regex for substituting comma with period in a string of digits

Tags: pcre, bbedit

Assuming a string of minimum one digit to the left of the decimal and minimum one to the right

```
0,0
```

when replacing the comma for a period, the replace function is not returning a proper result as the period in GREP signifies any character.

What is the proper way to find and replace the comma with a period in such a context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(\d+)\,(\d+)`searches for any number of digits around a comma, while
`\1\.\2` maintains the two numerical propositions and substitutes the comma with a period.